# Conditional types: using interface keys and their types as parameters for a function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, conditional-types

I want to have a global interface in my library which should be extendable via TypeScript's declaration merging to provide convenient auto-completion and also type safety:

```js
declare namespace Library {
  export interface Events {
    'login': (username: string, password: string) => void;
    'do-something': (message: number) => void;
    'do-nothing': () => void;
  }
}
```

I then have some function `on` which should dynamically find out it's parameters types from said interface. Currently, my first parameter is just `keyof Library.Events`.

```js
function onEvent<T extends keyof Library.Events>(
  name: T,
  callback: Library.Events[T]
): void {
  console.log(name + " uses callback: " + callback);
}

// so this should be allowed:
onEvent('login', (username: string, password: string) => undefined);

// but this should be not:
onEvent('login', (message: number) => undefined);
```

I tried typing my second parameter to match the interfaces' type, but as `T` is still a union of all keys, i can match any given callback signature.

The reason for not using an object here is that this should be a public-facing interface for developers to extend, so it should be as simple as possible (and also readable) to extend on.

Knex (a SQL query builder) is doing something like that:
http://knexjs.org/#typescript-support
but i was not able to reverse-engineer its functionality from their source code.

Comment: It seems like it works: https://tsplay.dev/NBzzbN

Comment: You will have probably have problems within the function body because `T` could be a union instead of a single name, but you can assert with `as` to avoid those.

Comment: This is very interesting, even the autocompletion is on point. I am using VS code and TypeScript 4.2.3, is there any known setting that could cause this weird difference in behavior?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the `as` implementation?

Comment: Sure: https://tsplay.dev/mA77Xw

Comment: Thank you very much! Take my imaginary comment-upvote and answer confirmation :)

Comment: There is a way to avoid the assertion using paired tuple arguments, but it's not very readable: https://tsplay.dev/mpllBm